# How to set image to UIImageView which is fetching asynchronously in another viewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I am relatively new to IOS programming.

I have a `NSObject` "Places" which is given below.

```
@interface Places : NSObject

 @property(strong) NSString *placeName;
 @property(strong) UIImage *placeImage;

@end
```

I am listing the array of Places objects in UITableView. On `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` images are fetching asynchronously from web urls. On `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, I pass the respective 'Places' object to another ViewController (detailViewController).  In that detailViewController, I uses below code to display the image in a `UIImageView`.

```
self.imageView.Image = self.myPlaces.placeImage
```

My problem is when I pass that object, the image needn't be fetched to placeImage. Is there anyway to update the `self.imageView` on successive completion of image fetching to `placeImage` in mainViewController.

My code is given below. It is called in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` of mainViewController.

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://imageurl_goes_here"];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if(imageData != nil)
            {
              place.placeImage = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
              cell.cellImageView.image = place.placeImage;
            }

        });
    });
```

Comment: Please provide your code for loading the image. It is likely there is a completion handler or callback.

Comment: Are you tapping the table row before the image is loaded fully?

Comment: @Rashmi Ranjan mallick Sometimes, Yes. I know the problem. But I am asking how to rectify it without blocking the user till asynchronous calls completes

Comment: Ya. I just wanted to check the issue. Still searching for a solution!!

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are some techniques to archive that:

- You can notify your second view controller every time you received image. E.g. in your inner `dispatch_async`. But this requires main controller to know much about second one.
- You can use [Key-Value Observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) technique to observe every place's image updating. In this case you might also want to use some handy library that will do sanity for you (like unsubscribing when object is deallocated, otherwise you will get crash) like [that one](https://github.com/iMartinKiss/Block-KVO) or any other.

[This post](http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/) of Matt Thompson may be helpful on other types of communications between instances.